# SVG animation issue with <style> tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to add the CSS code inside the HTML but I am having trouble getting the SVG animation to work. What am I doing wrong here? My guest is that I am referencing `<style>` wrongly but after a couple of tries I can't make it work.

```
<svg>
  <style type="text/css">
    .spinner {
      animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    .path {
      stroke: hsl(210, 70, 75);
      stroke-linecap: round;
      animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    }

      @keyframes rotate {
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }

      @keyframes dash {
        0% {
          stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
        50% {
          stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: -35;
        }
        100% {
          stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: -124;
        }
      }
  </style>
  <svg class="spinner">
      <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"</circle>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/XMaJYV?editors=1100)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your animation works.** You messed up stroke color definition. `hsl(210, 70%, 75%);`
 and circle elements opening tag is missing closing bracket `>`

```
<circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5" > </circle>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <style type="text/css">
    .spinner {
      animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
      transform-origin:center center;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  
    .path {
      stroke: hsl(210, 70%, 75%);
      stroke-linecap: round;
      animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
  
      @keyframes rotate {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(359deg);
        }
      }
  
      @keyframes dash {
        0% {
          stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
        50% {
          stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: -35;
        }
        100% {
          stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
          stroke-dashoffset: -124;
        }
      }
  </style>
  <g class="spinner">
      <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: and i thank you for an inspiration how to tackle down an arc loader.

Comment: @DiegoOriani By the way, you probably didn't mean to use svg twice. Instead group and fix the rotate animation. - updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the html tag for circle

```
<circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"</circle>
```

should be

```
<circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
```